# Insertion Sorting compareTo()

Tags: java, sorting, compareto, insertion

So I have a list of objects that I would like to sort based on the trait of each name of the object (In alphabetical order). We are required to have it "Roughly" in alphabetical order, so I have what I thought was a mediocre implementation of the insertion sorting algorithm. However, I'm only able to sort one item properly alphabetically. I have been at this for hours and seem to have hit a road block.

```js
public void sort(){
  int i=1;
  while(list[i]!=null) { //while there is an element in the array
    String one=list[i-1].getName(); //get the name of the "first object"
    String two=list[i].getName();  //get the name of the "second object"

    if(two.compareTo(one)==0){ // if equal move on 
      i++;
    }
    else if(two.compareTo(one)<0){// two is before one
      Contact temp =list[i-1];  //store this temporarily
      list[i-1]=list[i]; //swap them
      list[i]=temp; //put temp back where it belongs
      i++;  //check next elements
    }
    i++
  }
}
```

Here is what is list, before, and after the sort...http://image.prntscr.com/image/698cf44309ee43c29532ebe71a4925fe.png

Comment: Maybe this will make it a bit more clear...http://image.prntscr.com/image/2ed8b8c8a2b94bebb19486d431da3fe6.png

Comment: Did I really stump the stack overflow community :D O_o

Comment: In a way, I suppose you did.  You left key bits of information out of your question and made everyone guess, and some of the Stack Overflow community guessed wrong.  If you want to think of that as stumping the community, I can't stop you.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to understand how insertion sort works.

- You pick an element from the unsorted half of the list (O(n))
- Try to insert the newly picked element to the sorted half of the list (O(n))

So, insertion sort is O(n^2), meaning it requires a nested loop, at least.

Here is a modified version:

```
    int i = 1;
    while(list[i] != null) {
        // i divides sorted and unsorted
        // try to insert i to the right place, so loop j from i-1 to 0
        int j = i;
        while (j > 0) {
            String one = list[j-1].getName();
            String two = list[j].getName();
            int cmp = one.compareTo(two);
            if (cmp <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            Contact temp = list[j-1];
            list[j-1] = list[j];
            list[j] = temp;
            --j;
        }
        ++i;
    }
```

Comment: No difference I'm afriad: http://image.prntscr.com/image/7e6dde971d2f4ef687d415fb50ea2daf.png

Comment: I have run it with your example. At least it works for me. I get contacts in this order : Alex Bob Fred John steve

Comment: hmmm. so how are you viewing them? I don't see how it couldn't be working for me

Comment: @PhilpAdoni There's an `Empty` after the first two elements in your example.  I don't know what that means, since you didn't show us the method that prints the output.  But if it means `list[2]` is `null`, then your original code made it look like that's supposed to be the end of the array.  And that's the same assumption Xin appears to have made.  If a `null` in the array means something else, you need to let us know what's going on.

Comment: @PhilpAdoni And please don't use .png or other images to post your output, your program, or anything else that can be included in your question as text.

Comment: @ajb That was the problem, the null in the second element...God, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement insertion sort. I'll explain you a simpler way by which you can sort your array of objects by name as you have explained.
The key properties of **Insertion sort** is:

1. Insertion sort starts from he left end of the array and advances to
   right.
2. This sorting mechanism will not look into elements on the right,
   rather it focuses on the current encountered item and drags back
   that item to it's correct position.

Let's code up keeping these things in mind!!

```
    /*
     * Performs Insertion sort on given array of contacts!!
     */
    public static Contact[] sortContacts(Contact[] contacts){
        int n = contacts.length;
        // Advance the pointer to right
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            /*
             * Compare current item with previous item.
             * If current item is not in it's correct position,
             * swap until it's dragged back to it's correct position.
             * (Ascending order!!) 
             */
            for(int j = i; j > 0; j--){
                if(less(contacts[j], contacts[j - 1])){
                    swap(contacts, j, j - 1);
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return contacts;

    }

    private static boolean less(Contact a, Contact b){
        return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName()) < 0;
    }

    private static void swap(Contact[] contacts, int i, int j){
        Contact temp = contacts[i];
        contacts[i] = contacts[j];
        contacts[j] = temp;
    }
```

These three methods facilitates your sorting!!

Now to test it, let's create some contacts and sort them!!

```
        Contact one = new Contact();
        one.setName("tony");
        one.setPhone("6666");
        one.setMail("kkk@lll.com");

        Contact two = new Contact();
        two.setName("steve");
        two.setPhone("777");
        two.setMail("rrr@mmm.com");

        Contact three = new Contact();
        three.setName("clint");
        three.setPhone("333");
        three.setMail("ggg@sss.com");

        Contact four = new Contact();
        four.setName("bruce");
        four.setPhone("222");
        four.setMail("bbb@ccc.com");
```

Let's sort:

```
Contact[] res = Insertion.sortContacts(new Contact[]{one,two,three,four});
for(Contact c : res){
        System.out.println(c);
    }
```

This produces the output:

```
Contact [name=bruce, mail=bbb@ccc.com, phone=222]
Contact [name=clint, mail=ggg@sss.com, phone=333]
Contact [name=steve, mail=rrr@mmm.com, phone=777]
Contact [name=tony, mail=kkk@lll.com, phone=6666]
```

Which is sorted based on names of each contact!!
I hope this is what you were trying to achieve

Answer (score -1):

You can use `interface Comparable` for your class.

Example:

```
public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact> 

    // ...

    public int compareTo(Contact other) {
       return getName().compareTo(other.getName());
    }
}
```

Then if `list` is an array:

```
Arrays.sort(list);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not familair with this, and we had to do it the way I initially tried, nothing fancy :)

Comment: @PhilpAdoni what type is list?

Comment: It is contact objects

Comment: I mean, is it an array or something like ArrayList?

Comment: It is an array! We can't use lists here

Comment: This doesn't answer his question.  This appears to be a classroom assignment, and most likely they need to write the sort themselves instead of using built-in sort methods.

Comment: @ajb, the original question is not clear enough. It did not state compareTo is not an option.

Comment: Perhaps not.  But it's clearly a classroom assignment, and nobody in a classroom assignment writes out a sort algorithm unless they're required to--otherwise the professor would tell them about `Arrays.sort`.  Not 100% clear, but I've seen enough classroom assignments on StackOverflow to have a good idea of what goes on in class.

Comment: True, Then, the down vote should goes to the question, not the answer, right?

Comment: If you edit your answer in any way, I can remove the downvote.